# How to get the _id of one document MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using `MongoDB` and `Java-driver`.

I need to insert a document into MongoDB and retrieve the _id of this document. The `insert` method return a `[WriteResult][1]`.

I don't know how I have to use the WriteResult object to retrieve the _id, because I try to do this:

```
public void insertDocument(BasicDBObject fact){
    DBCollection coll = this.getCollection("facts");
    WriteResult result = coll.insert(fact);
    String id = (String) result.getField("_id");
    System.out.println("--------------------------->"+id);

}
```

And I have a null `String` in the `println`.

My question is how I can get the entire object (with _id) that I just inserted into the database.

Thanks!

Comment: `WriteResult` is a *status* object, not a copy of the item inserted into the collection, and note that `result.getField` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the `BasicDBObject` instance is inserted, the MongoDB driver modifies the instance in the terms of setting a value to the `_id` field (if you haven't specified such).

Therefore, you can still use the `fact` object and get the `_id` from there:

```
 System.out.println(fact.get("_id"));
```

Comment: Then, can my method return the BasicDBObjec to have my old object with  the correct _id??

Comment: Yes, you can return the `fact`. Ofcourse, you have to change the method signature to `public DBObject insertDocument(BasicDBObject fact)`

Comment: My last question. Can I mapped a BasicDBObject to a "Fact" object?

Comment: Hm...what is the Fact object ? Possibly you can, but you'd better create another thread and ask the question there. Let more people know about it :)

Comment: Sorry, it is a Object of my code. I was thinking to do something like to parse a BasicDBObject through a JSON string to my Fact Object

Comment: This answer also applies to the new (driver version 3.0+) [`Document`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/org/bson/Document.html) class. After inserting a `Document` call `getObjectId("_id")` to retrieve the server-generated `_id` field.